# Pandas merge error: timedate being converted to unix

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I have 2 data frames that are organized as follows:

```
eth_price.head(n=5)

Out[12]: 
                 time  eth_price
0 2017-08-28 16:19:00    344.021
2 2017-08-28 16:24:00    343.833
3 2017-08-28 16:29:00    343.643
4 2017-08-28 16:34:00    343.632
5 2017-08-28 16:39:00    343.456
btc_price.head(n=5)

Out[13]: 
                  time   btc_price
0  2017-08-27 22:50:00  4,389.6113
1  2017-08-27 22:51:00  4,389.0850
2  2017-08-27 22:52:00  4,388.8625
3  2017-08-27 22:53:00  4,389.7888
4  2017-08-27 22:56:00  4,389.9138
```

I am trying to merge them on `time` with the following code:

```
all_data = pd.merge(btc_price, eth_price, on = 'time', how = 'outer')
```

One data frame is 6195 rows and the other is 908. In theory, `all_data` should return 6195 rows with 3 columns (time, btc_price, eth_price).

For some reason, the `eth_price` timestamp which originally matches the `btc_price` timestamp- is being transformed into unix in the merged data frame like this:

```
time                btc_price      eth_price
1504304640000000000     NA           386.541
1504304940000000000     NA           386.48
1504305240000000000     NA           386.67199999999997
1504305540000000000     NA           386.37199999999996
1504305840000000000     NA           386.606
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**: this problem persists even when I explicitly define the timestamp of the eth_price data using, `eth_price[0] = pd.to_datetime(eth_price[0], unit = 's')`

Comment: How did you fix the conversion to datetime from your previous question?

Comment: Well, actually the problem there was the structure of the csv file itself...the rows were mismatched due to editing so I had to manually realign the columns

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `btc_price['time'].dtype
Out[8]: dtype('O')

eth_price['time'].dtype
Out[9]: dtype('<M8[ns]')` was the reason for the error. I fixed it by explicitly converting `btc_price.to_datetime` first and was then able to join the df's appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was unable to fix the conversion to unix timestamp for `eth_price` and I was also unable to figure out why it was happening in the first place.

So, my solution was to use `df.join` instead as follows:

```
all_data1 = btc_price.join(eth_price)
```

When I run this line of code, the `eth_price['time']` column remains in its original format.